# zipkin giving error with elasticsearch 7.x

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch, zipkin

I'm getting following errors when I connect zipkin into elasticsearch 7.14.1 and 7.7.1. it is wrokig fine with elasticsearch 6

elasticsearch-7.12.1, elasticsearch-7.14.1

```
  ERROR: cannot load service names: Request processing failed; nested exception is 
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: response for update-template failed: {"error": 
  {"root_cause":[{"type":"invalid_index_template_exception","reason":"index_template 
  [zipkin:span_template] invalid, cause [Validation Failed: 1: index_pattern [zipkin:span-] 
  must not contain a 
  ':';]"}],"type":"invalid_index_template_exception","reason":"index_template 
  [zipkin:span_template] invalid, cause [Validation Failed: 1: index_pattern [zipkin:span-] 
   must not contain a ':';]"},"status":400}
```

elasticsearch-7.0.0, elasticsearch-7.7.1

```
ERROR: cannot load service names: Request processing failed; nested exception is 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: response for update-template failed: {"error":{"root_cause": 
[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Setting index.mapper.dynamic was removed after 
version 6.0.0"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Setting index.mapper.dynamic 
was removed after version 6.0.0"},"status":400}
```

I' using `zipkin 2.11.7`
any guidance would be appreciated

Comment: you've got 2 problems I can see - index_pattern [zipkin:span-] must not contain a   ':' - and Setting index.mapper.dynamic was removed after version 6.0.0. so I would suggest looking at them separately

Comment: i have same problem, did you find any solution?